How to fix docker login for ECR failing with Segmentation fault (core dumped)?
I'm getting this error when running a pipeline on Gitlab.
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-south-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-south-2.amazonaws.com
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

The pipeline breaks in the service-talk-booking-docker-image-development job, that extends from service-talk-booking-docker-image.
service-talk-booking-docker-image:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/MY-USER-NAME/talk-booking:cicd-docker
  stage: docker
  services:
    - docker:24.0.6-dind
  before_script:
    - cd services/talk_booking/
    - poetry export --without-hashes --with-credentials -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region MY-AWS-REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.MY-AWS-REGION.amazonaws.com
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG" .
    - docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG"

service-talk-booking-docker-image-development:
  extends: .service-talk-booking-docker-image
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.MY-AWS-REGION.amazonaws.com/talk-booking-dev:development-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  rules:
    - if: '($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main") || ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event")'
      changes:
        - services/talk_booking/**/*


I tried many ways to avoid the Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device but always getting the Segmentation fault (core dumped)
My variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are not protected as indicated in the tutorial https://testdriven.io/courses/scalable-fastapi-aws.
What am I missing?
I tried with the solutions from this thread:
aws ecr saying "Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device" after copied cmd from "Amazon Container Services"
And also tried with the variables in GitLab as protected and unprotected.

As mentioned in this answer your aws ecr get-login-password --region MY-AWS-REGION is probably failing, try running just that command and you'll be able to see the real error and then solve it.
